# Why can't make-series operator be used inside 'fork' operator

Tags: kql

Why can't make-series operator be used inside *fork* operator, while *summarize* can ?

```
traces
| take 100
| fork
leg1 = (summarize count())
leg2 = (make-series count() on timestamp from ago(1h) to now() step 10m)
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Prefer using batch with materialize of tabular expression statements over [fork operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/forkoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer)."

```
// Data sample generation. Not part of the solution.
let traces = materialize(range i from 1 to 1000 step 1 | extend timestamp = ago(1h * rand()));
// Solution starts here.
let p_step = 10m;
let traces_100 = materialize(traces | take 100);
traces_100 | count;
traces_100 | make-series count() on timestamp from bin(ago(1h), p_step) to now() step p_step
```

| Count |
| --- |
| 100 |

| count_ | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| [7,19,11,15,18,19,11] | ["2022-10-13T11:40:00.0000000Z","2022-10-13T11:50:00.0000000Z","2022-10-13T12:00:00.0000000Z","2022-10-13T12:10:00.0000000Z","2022-10-13T12:20:00.0000000Z","2022-10-13T12:30:00.0000000Z","2022-10-13T12:40:00.0000000Z"] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA12PPW7DMAyF9wC5wxuloo3tOcjWuUsPELAJYwu1RENi0KDw4UsrBhpkJPl%20PjYN3kkJheI0MnpOnEmDpB0%20RDFRVsgFOjCKjNd62W5GVmimExccEEk5BxrDL7tMqWcEXLJEdFBB17YtivJk4wy%20KaczNEQuapVmp15cN%20AF5j077/1%20u2kafK5t5jWGgoEzr83TseYdLDvuH2GOVvYEtFLOUPrmBWaJf1DPOMk16fMymvqtWIp5q8B5GMs/d33wKyR3x/evK5Vffk7yY/oKed/%20AZ/7XK9mAQAA)